# Event that is triggered when a string from the resourcefile is loaded

Tags: c#, .net, string, resources, translation

I want a custom version of my strings in resource file but I dont want to create it completly new because it's just for a short period of time.

Is there any way to trigger an event when my program calls `Properties.Resources.MyString`so I can manipulate it before it is shown to the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by changing Resources class (look at generated code), but the drawback is that this class is regenerated each time you add/change something in resources file. You can omit that problem by implementing your own generation tool, read this: [Extended Strongly Typed Resource Generator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13830/Extended-Strongly-Typed-Resource-Generator)